# Connecting to MySql through ASP.NET using ODBC

Tags: c#, asp.net

help me with this issue please.

I'm trying to connect to MySql using ASP.Net.
i'm using this code to do this:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
//......
DataSet Mysql_ds = new DataSet();
OdbcConnection Mysql_con;

string Mysql_conStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 4.1         Driver};Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;uid=USER;pwd=PASS";

Mysql_con = new OdbcConnection(Mysql_conStr);
Mysql_con.Open(); 
//....
```

this code works well when i use it in C#, WindowsFrom Application, BUT When I use this code in ASP.NET and upload it to my server, when i go to my website address, i get this error :

**Exception Details:** System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

the error line is in the last line ( Mysql_con.open() ).

I have searched a lot and do some tries but nothing solved yet :(
How should I solve this problem!
OR
Is there any better way to create mysql connection !?

here is some information about the MySql installed on the server site :

localhost:
Server version: 4.1.22-community-nt
Protocol version: 10
Server: localhost via TCP/IP
User: USER@127.0.0.1

phpMyAdmin - 2.10.1:
MySQL client version: 5.0.45
Used PHP extensions: mysql

Answer (score 0):

You adjust your data source, your server name

```
string Mysql_conStr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 4.1 Driver};
                       Server=/*ReplaceYourValue*/; //<-- Ajust the value
                       Database=DBNAME;uid=USER;pwd=PASS";
```